# Stop AWS CloudFront stripping custom domain when re-directing

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, zappa

I have CloudFront caching a Django Lambda (Zappa) deployment. Everything is working fine except that when I visit my custom domain such as [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) it is re-directing to the Lambda execution URL like https://1234xb7gmc.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ rather than keeping the custom domain.

I think the flow is as follows: Custom Domain > CloudFront Domain > Lambda Domain

I just want it so that at the end, the user is still using the custom domain and not the Lambda one (even though behind the scenes they're being invoked).

Is there a name for this behavior?

Comment: CloudFront isn't doing this. I think either API Gateway is issuing a redirect, because you haven't configured it to be aware of the custom domain, or possibly django is issuing the redirect. If you enabled API Gateawy logging you should be able to see what is issuing the HTTP redirect response.

Comment: In the CloudFront logs I can see requests to the custom domain get 301 re-directed to the CloudFront domain. In the API Gateway logs I just see requests to the Lambda execution URL. I can't find any logs which show a re-direction from the CloudFront URL to the Lambda one.

Comment: Can you include those CloudFront logs in your question?

Comment: Yeah, I've added both and singled out the first API Gateway request log.

Comment: The only 301 redirect I see here is CloudFront redirecting the HTTP request to HTTPS. Are you saying this redirect is also changing the domain name?

Comment: Also, does your CloudFront domain name and SSL setup look like this? https://advancedweb.hu/assets/posts/custom_domain_route53/cloudfront_cert-930722dab6615a2e38babccea911fd0afb046615b3f25bae4d007e83dabf12f5.png

Comment: I don't think they show the domain changing, but I think it's happening somewhere on or in-between CloudFront and APIGateway. Yes, my domain name and SSL looks like that

Comment: You should be able to examine the HTTP response in your browser's developer console to see if the 301 response redirecting you to HTTPS is also redirecting you to a different domain.

Comment: There is a 301 redirect to the execute URL which makes sense from a backend routing perspective, but I don't know how I would preserve the custom domain for the user. I don't see a step like this mentioned in any guides, it's all handled by Zappa

Comment: No that doesn't make sense from a backend routing perspective. CloudFront proxies requests, it's not supposed to redirect the client to access the backend directly. Please check that your CloudFront settings match that image I linked, and also that you have configured the custom domain name in API Gateway.

Comment: If I add example.com as a CNAME in CloudFront am I supposed to add example.com as a custom domain in API Gateway? When I try it gives me an error "CNAMEAlreadyExists", that it's already in-use by CloudFront

Comment: You need to examine the responses in your browsers developer console to determine if it is CloudWatch or API Gateway that is sending the 301 redirect.

Comment: Fixed this, thanks for your help. This came down to DNS, Chrome was doing some sort of local browser cache messing things up. Curl'ing and using Incognito or another browser works fine.